# conversion to XML in Node JS

Tags: node.js, xml

I am working on my application using node js for the backend, and I want to implement this process. Each file (can be pdf, excel , ..) added to folder number 1 in my backend must be detected automatically and generated from it an xml format that will be added to second folder that will contain the xml versions of files in the first directory.

I tried to use xml builder. I did install it.  Then, I tried to test manually by adding a file in the first folder:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import xmlbuilder from 'xmlbuilder';

const sourceFolder = 'back/server/sourceFolder'; // Folder where your files are added
const xmlFolder = 'back/server/XMLFolder'; // Folder to store generated XML files

// Function to convert file content to XML
function convertToXML(fileContent) {
    const xml = xmlbuilder.create('root')
        .ele('data', fileContent)
        .end({ pretty: true });
    return xml.toString();
}

// Function to watch the source folder for file changes
function watchFolder() {
    fs.watch(sourceFolder, (eventType, filename) => {
        if (eventType === 'rename' && filename) {
            const filePath = path.join(sourceFolder, filename);
            fs.promises.readFile(filePath, 'utf8')
                .then(data => {
                    const xmlData = convertToXML(data);
                    const xmlFilePath = path.join(xmlFolder, `${filename}.xml`);
                    return fs.promises.writeFile(xmlFilePath, xmlData);
                })
                .then(() => {
                    console.log(`File converted to XML and saved: ${xmlFilePath}`);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error('Error:', err);
                });
        }
    });
}

// Ensure the XML folder exists
if (!fs.existsSync(xmlFolder)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(xmlFolder);
}

// Start watching the folder
watchFolder();

console.log('Watching for changes in', sourceFolder);
```

Comment: can you explain more please

Comment: I have 3 types : excel / R4j / word , so is it possible ? i found that i can convert from Excel to json and from json to xml , is it doable ?